# The XAML Binary Format (XBF) generator reported syntax error '0x09c6' in UWP with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

Could someone tell me why this exact error occurs in UWP in Visual Studio? The pattern that I have noticed is when a user control is used inside a data template like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="model:ValueModel">
    <local:myControl Value="{x:Bind}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

This error comes up in random places and random times during compilation especially if a new blank page is created or if the folder structure is changed.
How do I check the output of the XBF generator and find what is wrong?
Please help!

Comment: Hello, this error is often caused by the use of inappropriate binding statements. Can you show a more complete code so that we can analyze the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error, and it turned out to be because I tried to assign an attached property with the wrong base class on my page, like:

```
<local:NavigablePage
...
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject.Views">
    <Page.Resources>
    ...
```

instead of

```
<local:NavigablePage
...
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject.Views">
    <local:NavigablePage.Resources>
    ...
```